# New Relic Browser Proxy Support

Tags: reactjs, proxy, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have an application written using `reactJS`, and `NodeJS`. The application is deployed securely on the cloud. Recently, I am trying to integrate new relic with every component of my application. I successfully integrated it with the NodeJS backend.

Nonetheless, I have a problem with the browser agent. As a matter of fact, the problem is as follows: I would like New Relic Browser to, instead of communicating directly with the New Relic SaaS platform directly, to pass through a proxy server that I set up. This is done for IP whitelisting issues.

The question is: is it possible to configure the New Relic Browser agent to pass hit my proxy servers, rather than hitting the New Relic servers directly? IF yes, how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up proxy details in the Node.JS setup file.
There is documentation with all parameters that can be set up, please review it:

- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/nodejs-agent-configuration

Can you also clarify how is your Browser agent setup, there is a couple of ways that it can be set up, please see the docs below:

- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/browser-monitoring/installation/install-browser-monitoring-agent

So you may play around with node.js settings, that should work.

Also, you may bring this question to [New Relic Explorers Hub](https://discuss.newrelic.com/)

Hope this will be of some use to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I already contacted the New Relic support. They replied that they do not support proxying. Nonetheless, they supplied us with the domain names with which the agent communicates. Sadly, this is not enough for our use case